# XCode 9: Module compiled with Swift 3.0.2 cannot be imported in Swift 3.2

Tags: ios, swift, realm, xcode9

I'm trying to build a project using Realm which is installed using pods. I've done this:

```
   1) Updated to XCode 9
   2) Run "pod update".  Note the podfile has SWIFT_VERSION set to 3.2 
   3) Checked in XCode settings that Swift Language version is set to 3.2
        for all the projects and targets.
   4) Deleted derived data 
   5) Cleaned everything 
   6) Quit and re-launched XCode 
   7) Rebuilt everything, including explicitly rebuilding the Realm targets
```

Despite everything being set to Swift 3.2, despite cleaning everything, despite deleted derived data, despite rebuilding everything. Still I keep getting this error:

> "Module compiled with Swift 3.0.2 cannot be imported in Swift 3.2".

It is saying this for the RealmSwift library.

Why, when the RealmSwift target is set to 3.2, and it has been rebuild, why why why is it still saying its 3.0.2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

1. Remove `RealmSwift` from your pod file
2. Run pod update
3. Re-add `RealmSwift` to your pod file
4. Run pod update
5. Clean your project
6. Build and run

Comment: I get this now though "The following binaries use incompatible versions of Swift: RealmSwift & my app" But everything in both is set to 3.2.

Comment: Now do the following: 1: Clean the project. 2: Close project and quit Xcode.
3: Clean derived data. 4: Open the project again and re-run

Comment: Still the same thing

Comment: @Piepants, checkout [this](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/3951) link. This will help you, you need to set the Swift version.

Comment: Thanks for the link, the pods file already does have the swift version set (to 3.2). If I can't solve this I think I'll just update everything to swift 4 as its something that will need doing eventually, and the process of doing that might bring everything into line.